# MVC: Client validation on list of object (At least one)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, validation, object, client

I want to implement client validation on a list of objects. I want to make sure that the list has at least one object, so I used custom validation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361607/807223) and made it client validable. This works well when the list is of simple datatype like an int.
That is

```
public List<int> var{get; set;}
```

With this I can include a Listboxfor in my view and when the form containing the list is submitted, client validation kicks in. However I now have a list of objects

```
public List<MyClass> var{get; set;}
```

Items are added to this list dynamically. I can therefore not have a ListBoxFor in my View. How can i display the list in my View so that that client validation picks it up?

Comment: I would recommend using Remote validations for this. Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: So, what do you have in your View?

Comment: I have a button to generate the list item, and the items are bound to the model